# ファイルダウンロード後にダウンロードに用いた一時フォルダを削除したい

Tags: javascript, python

Pythonでユーザにユーザごとに作成した一時フォルダ内のファイルをダウンロードさせるようなWebアプリケーションを作っています。ダウンロード用に作成したフォルダはユーザがそのファイルをダウンロードしたあとに残ってしまいます。これをユーザのダウンロード後に削除するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

1つ考えた案としてはフォルダを削除するルートをサーバサイドに作っておきダウンロードボタンをクリックしたことをJavaScriptで検知して、Ajaxを使ってそのルートを呼び出しフォルダを削除するというものです。しかし、これはダウンロードが完了する前にフォルダが削除されてしまうと考えられます。

他に方法はあるのでしょうか。なにかアイデアを頂けますでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お望みの方法は、ダウンロード後、`直ちに`削除する、というものでしょうか？

もし単に一時ファイルを削除するのであれば、cron などで、1時間に1回削除する、という方法があると考えます。

1時間以内に作成されたファイルを除外すれば、ダウンロードが終わっていないファイルを削除することは無いかと。

[find コマンドを使って指定日時より古いファイルを消す。 | Drowsy Dog's Diary](http://ka-zoo.net/2013/02/find-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E6%97%A5%E6%99%82%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E5%8F%A4%E3%81%84%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92/)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
herokuの無料プランを利用している関係上プロセスを増設できないので、ダウンロードごとにシェルスクリプトを実行するようにしました。